# I have unwanted space around the images in my responsive slider when my image shrinks

Tags: html, css

[I have unwanted space around the images in my responsive slider when my image shrinks.](http://www.cottongwa.org/new-cgwa/)

I am using Bootstrap on a redesign of a website I designed. My problem is that I want the images inside the slider at the top of the page to resize. I used img-responsive, which makes the images resize. However, that causes the div around the image to add unwanted space around the image. I need the image to be the same size as the container is with the gray border. As the images in the slider get smaller, the container should shrink down with the image, not add extra space around it.

```css
.img-responsive .thumbnail>img,
.thumbnail a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */


/* Carousel base class */

.carousel {
  height: 425px;
  margin: 110px 0 20px 0;
}


/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}


/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */

.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="first-slider">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <!-- Item 1 -->
          <div class="item active slide1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="container">
                <img class="responsive" src="images/cotton-field.jpg" alt="Cotton Field">
                <!-- Slide One Image courtesy https://www.bsr.org/our-insights/blog-view/three-steps-tackle-raw-materials-inside-out-supply-chain-collaboration -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Item 2 -->
          <div class="item slide2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="container">
                <img class="responsive" src="images/bales.jpg" alt="Cotton Bales">
                <!-- Slide Two Image courtesy http://www.aiighk.com/our-business.php -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Item 3 -->
          <div class="item slide3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="container">
                <img class="responsive" src="images/pickers.jpg" alt="Cotton Picker">
                <!-- Slide Three Image courtesy http://aiighk.com/growers-services.php -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Item 4 -->
          <div class="item slide4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="container">
                <img class="responsive" src="images/warehouse.jpg" alt="Cotton Warehouse">
                <!-- Slide Four Image courtesy of https://nca-la.com/ -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some (or most) browsers set a margin on the `body` element by default. Add the following CSS to remove these margins:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of max-width:100%; , try width:auto;