# How to remove a gap around the image in div and table that appears when the image shrinks?

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio, window-resize

How could I remove the unwanted space above and below the images in div and table elements that appear when the images shrink? I am otherwise happy with the behaviour of my images: they shrink, and the aspect ratio does not change.

My question is similar to [I have unwanted space around the images in my responsive slider when my image shrinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937236), but that one did not get any helpful answers. My question might be simpler though.

The original webpage is [here](http://www.yu51a5.com/two-types-of-primates/).

The snipper is below. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu51a5/vsyxont6/34/), if it is more convenient.

```css
img {
object-fit: contain;
max-width:90%; 
height: 450px;
}

html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

table, div {
  max-width:90%; 
  border:5px solid #000000;
}

table{
border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Typical Behaviour</td><td><img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/SocialScience/Gorillas_fight_over_a_tomato.jpg" /></td><td><img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/SocialScience/Tamarin_GoldenLion.jpg" /></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
***
<div><img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/SocialScience/GrandBudapestHote.jpg" /><img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/SocialScience/JB.jpeg" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img {
object-fit: contain;
max-width:90%; 
max-height: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add 2 attribute in table tag cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" or add below css to remove space

```
table{
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

and you set `height="450px"` and `height="250"` just remove it always keep auto height in responsive layout.

check you fiddle i updated there.

```
<table style="max-width:90%; border:5px solid #000000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Comment: Updated the snipped and JSFiddle; no joy unfortunately